# How do I install a package to a "standard prefix"?

Tags: software-installation, package-management, configuration

OS: Linux Mint 18.3

I'm currently trying to install the latest stable release of [cryptsetup](https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup). It's installed, but as usual the Synaptic version is very old (1.6.6 compared to 2.3.2).

Running `./configure` as per the "INSTALL" document, I found some problems which were solved with [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/956215/228028). `./configure` then failed again with:

```
checking for json-c... no
configure: error: Package requirements (json-c) were not met:

No package 'json-c' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables JSON_C_CFLAGS
and JSON_C_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.
See the pkg-config man page for more details.
```

This then led to me to [this page](https://github.com/json-c/json-c), where I tried following the "Build instructions". I ran the `git clone` instruction from the directory where you find the "configure" file for cryptsetup.

The `cmake` command seemed to finish OK, but running `./configure` again (for cryptsetup) I get the same error.

I don't understand this business of a "non-standard prefix". Can someone say how I install this json-c package to the "standard prefix"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the `libjson-c-dev` package:

```
apt-get install libjson-c-dev
```

That will provide the development headers and libraries that are needed to build `cryptsetup`.

If you continue to receive error messages like that, then it means that you need to install the package that's specified.

Answer (score 0):

[Nasir Riley’s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/584385/86440) gives the correct solution to make `json-c` available to the `cryptsetup` build.

Regarding your question about “standard prefixes”, they’re the base locations where build tools (in this instance, `pkg-config`) look for files; in most distributions that’s `/usr` and `/usr/local`. In your case, building `json-c` from source would place the files in directories under `/usr/local`. The reason it didn’t is that you stopped too early: the `cmake` step doesn’t build or install anything, you need to follow the build instructions further down, with `make` and `sudo make install`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation