# What to do about a make failure?

Tags: make

This follows from [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/584384/220752).

I am trying to install cryptsetup 2.3.2. The pre-existing version is 1.6.6 (installed on the system, and "latest version" according to Synaptic).

So I followed those instructions, installed the blkid dev library... then

```
 mike@M17A ~/Download...ptsetup-2.3.2/cryptsetup-2.3.2 $  sudo make
[sudo] password for mike: 
make  all-recursive
make[1]: Entering directory '/home/mike/Downloads/cryptsetup-2.3.2/cryptsetup-2.3.2'
Making all in po
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mike/Downloads/cryptsetup-2.3.2/cryptsetup-2.3.2/po'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mike/Downloads/cryptsetup-2.3.2/cryptsetup-2.3.2/po'
Making all in tests
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mike/Downloads/cryptsetup-2.3.2/cryptsetup-2.3.2/tests'
make[2]: Nothing to be done for 'all'.
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mike/Downloads/cryptsetup-2.3.2/cryptsetup-2.3.2/tests'
make[2]: Entering directory '/home/mike/Downloads/cryptsetup-2.3.2/cryptsetup-2.3.2'
  CC       lib/luks2/libcryptsetup_la-luks2_disk_metadata.lo
In file included from ./json-c/json_object.h:36:0,
                 from ./json-c/json.h:27,
                 from lib/luks2/luks2_internal.h:27,
                 from lib/luks2/luks2_disk_metadata.c:24:
./json-c/json_inttypes.h:9:25: fatal error: json_config.h: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
Makefile:2072: recipe for target 'lib/luks2/libcryptsetup_la-luks2_disk_metadata.lo' failed
make[2]: *** [lib/luks2/libcryptsetup_la-luks2_disk_metadata.lo] Error 1
make[2]: Leaving directory '/home/mike/Downloads/cryptsetup-2.3.2/cryptsetup-2.3.2'
Makefile:2314: recipe for target 'all-recursive' failed
make[1]: *** [all-recursive] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory '/home/mike/Downloads/cryptsetup-2.3.2/cryptsetup-2.3.2'
Makefile:1134: recipe for target 'all' failed
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

NB in the above: note the "fatal error".  json_config.h is apparently missing. I have no idea why this might be.

This leads me to ask two questions:

1. what is one meant to do in a situation like this?
2. why don't download sites just let you download a pre-built version of the app? Why are we forced to go through the complicated and failure-prone process of actually compiling and building an app like this?

Comment: Debian example : https://packages.debian.org/search?suite=default&section=all&arch=any&searchon=contents&keywords=json_config.h → `libjson-c-dev`

Comment: Also, do not use `sudo` for `make`. Bad security

Comment: Did you actually install the `libjson-c-dev` package from your other question? The missing header file is provided by it. The developer hasn't released a pre-built version of the app so it'll have to be compiled from source until then. The same is true for many other apps.

Comment: @NasirRiley Yes, I did install that package. That's why I'm baffled by the error. And yes, I've had this experience before of having to build apps (although I'd forgotten the protocol: `make` and then `make install`). I don't understand why developers choose not to provide a pre-built version. Some apps' installation may involve intricate modification of the OS's configuration... but it seems that usually this is not the case, so there seems little justification for not just providing a version which runs straight out of the box.